# How to read/retrieve hashed password from sqlite db to login using php

Tags: php, sqlite

I have successfully created registration form with hashed password as shown below. I am not able to log In using the username and hashed password that I have stored in my SQLite db.

I can log in if the password is store as plain text, but I want the password to be hashed. Please help me how can I read the hash password which matches the username to login. I am new to php and this is the first time I am working with SQLite db as well as php. Please help me, I have been trying to do this for past few days now :(
Any help or guidance would be great.

(I have noticed there is not much with php and sqlite that I could find online and the similar questions I have seen on stack flow is related to mysql mostly. Also, I apologize if I am posting it right or if it is too easy of an answer because I am beginner and new to this. Thank you)

Here is how I am storing the password in hash in my **registration.php** which is working:

```
if(ISSET($_POST['register'])) {
//setting the variables
$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
**//hashing the password
$password = PASSWORD_HASH($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);**
$email = $_POST['email'];
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    
//Inserting
$query = "INSERT INTO myTable (user_id, password, email, first_name, last_name) VALUES(:user_id, :password, :email, :first_name, :last_name)";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
    $stmt->bindParam(':first_name', $first_name);
    $stmt->bindParam(':last_name', $last_name);
    
//check to see if the exec of the query is success
    if($stmt->execute()){
        $_SESSION['success'] = "Account is created successfully";
            
    //redirect to login
            header("location:index.html");
    }
}
```

Here is my **login.php**

```
    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
    $password = ($_POST['password']);
    $query = "SELECT count(*) as count FROM myTable WHERE user_id=:user_id AND password=:password";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $user_id);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);    
    // this is to execute 
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    //this fetching from the db the user name and password. Where SQLite3_NUM returns an array by column number starting at 0 being the first
    $row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_NUM);
    
/*$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM lit_login_credentials WHERE user_id = ?");
$stmt->execute([$_POST['user_id']]);
$stmt = $stmt->fetch();*/

    //This is checking if the input login and user in the db is only entered once then it will go though else if not found then it will stay on the same page. 
    if($row[0] == 1 /*&& $user_id && password_verify($_POST['password'], $user_id['password'])*/){
        //$out = "Success";
        header('location: admin.php');
    } else {
        //$out = "invalid username or password";
        //echo "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Invalid username or password</div>";
        $_SESSION['error'] = "Invalid username or password";
        header('location: index.php');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [password_verify](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to compare the db password to the entered password.

Program should SELECT password from myTable WHERE user matches the entered user code. If any rows are returned (i.e. user is found), use `password_verify` to compare what is returned from the db and what is entered by the user. (Similar to the commented bit later in the code).

Comment: How would I compare to the hashed value entered on login page? Is there like a syntax or source you can point me to because I am not sure how to compare and that is what I am trying to ask help for.